# How to get element in element from the list of elements in Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

On the page I have, for example, list of cars, all of them have the same buttons, like "select" (locators are the same for all select buttons):

In my code, I'm using this to get the list of WebElements for cars:

```
List<WebElement> allCars = driver.findElements(By.Xpath(ListOfAvailableCars));
```

Then, I'm getting WebElement for 5th car and I'm locating select button for this car:

```
allCars.get(4).findElement(By.Xpath(SelectButtonLocator)).click();
```

But "select" button pressed for the 1st car in the list.

Is it possible to just locate button and other elements in this particular element (to restrict Webdriver to this element only)?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: Depending on your XPath, you could use e.g. //div[@class='my-class'][5] to get the fifth element (XPath element index is 1-based).

Comment: "SelectButtonLocator" xpath string should begin with a '.' to restrict searching within the desired element.

Comment: @Grasshopper thanks, it's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all!

Solved this problem by adding "." to the Xpath. @Grasshopper solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a locator to the button for each car.

With the *`List<WebeElement>`* find all buttons and click them by index.
*`list.get(1).click();`*

Second solution is to create xpath locator for each button.

First car

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@id='something'])[1]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate your webElement

```
List<WebElement> allCars = driver.findElements(By.Xpath(ListOfAvailableCars)/following-sibling::SelectButtonLocator);
```

then

```
allCars.get(4).click()
```

hope it will help.
if possible, please share the screenshot